# What does comma mean here in CSS3, between transition and transform?

Tags: css, less, css-transitions, css-transforms

Two questions please, as I'm new to CSS3:

**1)** I understand that `-XXX-transtion:  opacity .4s` below says to Webkit and Firefox browsers: *change opacity to zero over the course of 400ms.* But what does the comma right afterwards mean?

```
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .4s, -webkit-transform .4s;
-moz-transition: opacity .4s, -moz-transform .4s;
```

**2)** Given the `mixins.less` file below, how to rewrite the above statements?

```
.transform(@transform) {
    -webkit-transform: @transform;
    -moz-transform: @transform;
    -ms-transform: @transform;
    -o-transform: @transform;
    transform: @transform;
}

.transition(@transition) {
    -webkit-transition: @transition;
    -moz-transition: @transition;
    -ms-transition: @transition;
    -o-transition: @transition;
    transition: @transition;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your 1st question:

You can use commas in transitions to specify multiple styles for which transition has to be applied.For eg: the line `-webkit-transition: opacity .4s, -webkit-transform .4s`  would tell to apply the transition when opacity is being changed and when a transform is being done(can be a shape change,position change or size change depending on the type of transform)